# What is the Space Complexity of this given code snippet?

Tags: time-complexity, space-complexity

The time complexity is O(2^N). How to derive the space complexity for this code?

```
int f(int n){ 
   if(n <= 1){
      return 1;    
   }
   return f(n-1) + f(n-1);
}
```

Comment: What do you think the space complexity is? Why?

Comment: I didn't get the answer, that's why i asked the question

Comment: but you can at least perform *some* reasoning? For example what do you think will consume memory? Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Space Complexity of an algorithm is total space taken by the algorithm with respect to the input size. Space complexity includes both Auxiliary space and space used by input.**

[quick reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-86/)

Basically code snippet is a recursive code
for input n it recursively call for n-1

calling example for value 3:

f(3)
f(2) + f(2)
f(1) + f(1) [for one f(2) , like wise other two]

the order of execution will be like [DFS](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bfs-vs-dfs-binary-tree/) traversal.

Due recursion the program will reuse the same program space which used before.

max depth of the tree will results in the space complexity

**O(N) - where N is the input number**

for recursions to work program uses [Stack Memory](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/)